# Proving a sequence to be increasing

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, pi

> Define $$a_{2n}=\sqrt{a_nA_n}, \; \;\; A_{2n}=\frac{2A_na_{2n}}{A_n+a_{2n}},$$with $a_4=2$ and $A_4=4$. Prove that $a_4,a_8,a_{16},a_{32},\dots$ is increasing.

**My Attempt**

We write
$$\{a_{2^{n+1}}\}=\{a_4,a_8,\dots\}.$$ Then the sequence is increasing iff $$a_{2^{n+1}}\geqslant a_{2^{n}}.$$
Using the definitions, I get to the point where proving that the sequence is increasing is reduced to showing $$A_{2^{n-1}}\geqslant a_{2^n},$$ but I am stuck on how to show this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is your attempt?  Under "We write" the left side is a set with one element, while the right side is a set with many elements.  They cannot be equal.  The line under "Then the sequence is increasing" is correct.  In fact, $a_n$ is only defined if $n$ is a power of $2$.  A nit in the last inequality is that $A$ has subscripts, not superscripts.  I don't think you mean powers of $A$.  What does $\pi$ have to do with it?

Comment: @RossMillikan Probably my notation is confusing. In the first line I mean that the sequence $(a_{2^{n+1}})$ is equal to the right hand side. Why is the line under "then the sequence is increasing" necessarily correct? These sequences are expressions for the area of inscribed and circumscribed $n$-gons on the unit circle, that Archimedes used to calculate $\pi$.

Comment: @Ryuky Show that $a_{2^{n-1}} < a_{2^n} < A_{2^n} < A_{2^{n-1}}$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Defining sequences $b_n=\ln a_{2^{n+1}}$ and $B_n=\ln A_{2^{n+1}}$, the problem becomes showing that $(b_n)$ is increasing. Since $b_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(b_n+B_n)$, it is equivalent to show that $b_n < B_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. This is true for $n=1$, so we proceed by induction. Since $b_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(b_n+B_n)$ and $B_{n+1}=\ln 2 + B_n + b_{n+1} - \ln(e^{b_n}+e^{B_n})$, it is equivalent to show that $\ln(e^{b_n}+e^{B_n}) < \ln2 + B_n$, which is plainly true by the assumption that $b_n < B_n$. QED